# Python tldextract Error Reading TLD Cache File

Tags: python, python-3.x, tld

I'm trying to extract domain using tldextract

```
ext = tldextract.extract(editString2)
print (ext.domain)
```

but i get this error at the same time, anyway to stop this error? I'm getting the print and result but just trying to find a way to not let it show this error.

```
error reading TLD cache file C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.tld_set: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2350: character maps to <undefined>
Exception reading Public Suffix List url https://raw.github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/master/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat. Consider using a mirror or constructing your TLDExtract with `fetch=False`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\tldextract\tldextract.py", line 247, in _PublicSuffixListSource
    page = unicode(urlopen(url).read(), 'utf-8')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 156, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 475, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 513, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 595, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Pass `suffix_list_url="https://raw.github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/master/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat"`.

Comment: ?? How do i " Pass " it? Thanks in advance

Comment: As an argument to `extract`: `extract(suffix_list_url="...")`.

Comment: Close, but `extract` is a convenience that only takes 1 arg. To customize your extractions to use a different PSL URL, you need to construct a `TLDExtract(suffix_list_url="...")`. See my answer and the [docs](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract/tree/1.3.1#specifying-your-own-url-or-file-for-the-suffix-list-data).

Answer (score 5):

"mozilla/mozilla-central" on GitHub was renamed to "mozilla/gecko-dev", without a redirect, hence the 404. The URL is fixed in the latest version of `tldextract`, 1.3.1

If it hadn't been fixed though, you can manually provide a PSL URL to your own `TLDExtract` callable with the `suffix_list_url` kwarg. See the [docs](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract/tree/1.3.1#specifying-your-own-url-or-file-for-the-suffix-list-data).